# Delete PowerPoint Slide Design that isn't part of a named set using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-office, powerpoint, office-2010

I have a set of custom layouts that are my approved corporate standard. There is one master and 11 custom layouts.

Because users will likely be pasting in old content, I am aware that any slides they paste in will bring their corresponding layouts with them. What is the best way to write a button that will remove any custom layouts that aren't part of the approved set?

The code I have is as follows, but it gives me an error that says "Slide (unknown member) : Invalid Request. Can't delete master."

ANY help gratefully received!

```
Dim oDesign As design

For Each oDesign In ActivePresentation.Designs

    'if design name is CC standard then
    If oDesign.Name = CCSMNAME$ Then

        Dim oLayout As CustomLayout

        'Check the name of each layout against the permitted set, delete any that are additional
        For Each oLayout In oDesign.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts

            If oLayout.Name <> "Title Slide (Basic)" Or oLayout.Name <> "Title Slide (Standard Stock Image)" Or oLayout.Name <> "Title Slide (Image - Right)" Or oLayout.Name <> "Agenda" Or oLayout.Name <> "Body/Content (Basic)" Or oLayout.Name <> "Report (Approval and Disclaimer)" Or oLayout.Name <> "Report Body/Content" Or oLayout.Name <> "Divider" Or oLayout.Name <> "Quals (Basic -Right)" Or oLayout.Name <> "Quals (Basic - Left)" Or oLayout.Name <> "Content and Closing" Then
                oLayout.Delete
            End If

        Next oLayout

    Else

        'Else, the Design found is not the CC Master so delete it
        '(This runs for all remaining masters)
         oDesign.Delete

    End If

Next oDesign
```

**I am now using the following code - does anyone have any idea why instead of deleting all additional slide masters, it only deletes the next in the sequence and then exits?**

Sub CleanupTemplate()

```
    'Declare some variables
    Dim oDesign As design
    Dim oDesigns As Designs
    Dim oLayout As CustomLayout
    Dim masterCount As Long
    Dim layoutCount As Long
    Dim strInUse As String

    On Error Resume Next

   For Each oDesign In ActivePresentation.Designs

            If oDesign.Name = CCSMNAME$ Then

            MsgBox "The script has found " & oDesign.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts.Count & " layouts in the CC Master. There should be 11 in total. An integrity check will now run to remove any non-approved slide layouts."

                            'Loop through set backwards to keep integrity of data set when deleting
                            For layoutCount = oDesign.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts.Count To 1 Step -1

                                   Set oLayout = oDesign.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(layoutCount)
                                   Err.Clear

                                   'Check the name of each layout against the permitted set, delete any that are additional
                                   If checkAllowed(oLayout) = False Then
                                    oLayout.Delete
                                   End If

                                   If Err <> 0 Then
                                    strInUse = strInUse & oLayout.Name & " , "
                                   End If

                            Next layoutCount
                            MsgBox ("Any additional layouts deleted, cleanup of CC Master completed.")

             Else

                'Else, a Slide Master has been found that is not the CC Master so delete it
                MsgBox ("An additional Slide Master named " & oDesign.Name & " that is not CC approved has been detected. It is not in use, so it will be removed.")
                oDesign.Delete

             End If

    Next oDesign

    'Alert the user to any foreign slide designs found that couldn't be deleted
    If Len(strInUse) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "The following slide designs seem to be either in use, or protected: " & Left(strInUse, Len(strInUse) - 1)
    End If
```

End Sub

Function checkAllowed(olay As CustomLayout) As Boolean

```
    Select Case olay.Name

            Case Is = "Title Slide (Basic)", _
            "Title Slide (Image - Right)", _
            "Title Slide (Standard Stock Image)", _
            "Agenda", "Body/Content (Basic)", _
            "Report (Approval and Disclaimer)", _
            "Report Body/Content", _
            "Divider", _
            "Quals (Basic - Right)", _
            "Quals (Basic - Left)", _
            "Contact and Closing"

                'Return true if any of the above names are a match
                checkAllowed = True

            Case Else

                'Return false if no match found
                checkAllowed = False

    End Select
```

End Function

Comment: Do the ppt-files where a design needs to be deleted aldready have the approved CC master? You cannot delete a design if it is the only design in the PPT file... :)

Comment: thats right - so it looks for the CC Master (which is in every template!) and then it needs to find any layouts (or slide designs, whatever you want to call them!) that may have been added to CC Master and then delete them. Because the only designs that are approved are the ones included in the template

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you delete members of a collection in a For/Next loop, you'll run into the same problem.

Consider a collection of three objects (slides, masters, apples, whatever)

```
For Each Object in Collection
  If Object.MeetsSomeCondition Then
    Object.Delete
  End If
Next
```

So the first time through the loop, you delete an object.
The next time through the loop, the internal counter's looking for the second object in the collection, but since the collection only contains two objects now, it's actually looking at what WAS the third object.
The next time through the loop, the internal counter's looking for the third object, but since there are only two in the collection, you get an out of range error.

Instead, do this:

```
For X = Collection.Count to 1 Step -1
  If condition then Collection(x).delete
Next
```